# What is the difference between *ptr and ptr* in C?

Tags: c

In the below example of pointer to structure

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   struct siva {
   int a;
   };

   typedef struct siva *s1;

    void main()
   {
    s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(s1*));
    b->a=8;
    printf("\n The vlue is s1->a is %d",b->a);
    free(b);
  }
```

In the above code the variable b is not declared, but how this code works

In this line

```
   s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(s1*));
```

How the memory is allocated for b and why s1* is used in sizeof().
what is the difference between *s1 and s1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a declaration of `s1`'s type as a pointer to  `struct siva`

```
typedef struct siva *s1;
```

The following is a pointer to `s1` (e.g. pointer to pointer to `struct siva`)

```
s1*
```

The size given in malloc is wrong, it should be

```
s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(struct siva));
```

As `s1` points to `struct siva`. It works only because the address of the first element in the struct is the address of the struct, but this is basically a dangerous thing to do.

`b` is declared, in the same line it is assigned to:

```
    s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(s1*));
//  ^^^^
```

Note that in C you are not allowed to initialize a variable from a function's return value.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between s1 and s1*

- `sizeof(s1)` yields the size of `s1`, that is the size of a pointer to `siva`;
- `sizeof(s1*)` yields the size of a *pointer* to `s1`, that is the size of a pointer to a pointer to `siva`.

Finally, the line:

```
s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(s1*));
```

should read:

```
s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(struct siva));
```

Comment: it should be `s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(struct siva));` not `s1 b=(s1)malloc(sizeof(s1));`

Comment: How the variable b is declared, is it possible to declare a variable of type structure without using (int,char,float)

Answer (score 0):

This code *doesn't* work, at least not as the author intends.  `sizeof (s1*)` gives the size of a pointer to `s1`, which is the size of a pointer to a pointer to `struct siva`.

First of all, I recommend changing that line to read

```
s1 b = malloc(sizeof *b);
```

First, the cast is unnecessary since C89, and can actually cause problems.  Unless you're working with a *very old* (pre-C89) compiler, don't cast the result of `malloc` or `calloc`.

Secondly, I use the expression `*b` as the operand to sizeof, instead of using a type.  It's a little cleaner, and you don't have to remember to keep the type straight between the declaration of `b` and the `malloc` call.  Since the type of `b` is `s1`, which is a synonym for `struct siva *`, the type of `*b` is `struct siva`.

The general form of a `malloc` call should be

```
T *p = malloc(sizeof *p * number_of_elements);
```

or

```
T *p;
...  // some bit of code
p = malloc(sizeof *p * number_of_elements);
```

If you're allocating a single instance of `T`, you can obviously drop the `* number_of_elements` from the call to `malloc`.

Finally, a bit of advice - don't hide pointers behind typedefs.  `s1` doesn't indicate pointer-ness at all, so it's not immediately obvious that `b` *should* be the target of a `malloc` call.